die Regeln reinziehen
I have heard the following sentence in the "Spieleabend" movie:

Zieh dir die Regeln vorher rein, sonst blamierst du dich.

Context: A guy is telling his friend he should learn the rules of the board games he plans to play with the friends of a girl he recently started to go out with.
What is the meaning of "reinziehen" (informal version of "hereinziehen")? I cannot find it in DWDS or Word Reference. Is it "check out", "learn", "read" ? Is that a figurative meaning of "pull into" because the person will "pull the rules into his mind" ?

I like how you researched the topic to find an answer. For future reference, dwds actually does have the meaning, but you have to look at reinziehen directly: https://www.dwds.de/wb/reinziehen Here, we are talking about meaning 2b

I thought German verbs prefixed with her- and r- always had the same meaning. Tricky!

In principle you are right, but omitting the her- is a way of talking more informally. This occasionally gives rise to a more slang meaning of the verb.

sich etwas reinziehen is a slang expression that roughly translates to "to consume something" (stemming as you correctly assumed from the literal meaning "to pull something into oneself").
It is most often used figuratively in the sense of cognitively consuming something, i.e. "to receive", "to perceive", "to grasp", "to understand", "to look at". In the case of your example, it translates "to familiarize oneself with the rules".
An example for the more literal meaning is

Nach dem Abendessen hat er sich noch drei Stück Kuchen reingezogen. ("After dinner he was gobbling down three pieces of cake.")

An example for the figurative meaning is

Zieh dir das mal rein! ("Get this!")


As mentioned above, the meaning in the question is 2b in DWDS, and I think the more literal meaning you're talking about is 2a. DWDS also says that you're watching, listening, etc. without much mental effort. So when applied to the rules of a game, perhaps "skim" might be a better translation than "read".

@RDBury I don't fully agree with that definition of DWDS, I don't think reinziehen implies ease. Especially in the example in OP, I think, it is not implied at all, quite the opposite. I read the sentence to express that the person should familiarize themselves closely with the rules. But it is also a movie script and it sounds like someone adding slang for trying to be cool, which makes the whole thing a little harder to interpret.

A close idiom in English: Sich den Prüfungsstoff reinziehen – to cram for an exam.

"reinziehen" if related to learning things stresses that one needs/wants to learn something but will not have fun with it. The most common context is to learn prior to school exams, any other exams, to dig through technical/engineering manuals etc.
